# How to programmatically remove anchors from a regular expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Consider:

```
regex1 = /\A[a-z0-9\-\_]+\z/

regex2 = remove_anchors(regex1) # => /[a-z0-9\-\_]+/
```

How to implement a `remove_anchors` function that *programmatically* removes any [anchors](http://regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`\A`, `\z`, `^`, `$`) from `regex1`, producing `regex2`? Is it even possible to modify an existing regular expression like this in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
def remove_anchors(regex)
   pattern = regex.source.gsub(/\A(?:\\A|\^)|(?:\\[zZ]|\$)\z/, '')
   return Regexp.new(pattern);
end
```

And here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/6nrH41)

The regex literal notation `/.../` compiles the regex and its string pattern can be obtained via the *source* property. With `gsub`, the anchors like `^`, `$`, `\A` and `\z` can be removed from the string pattern.

Comment: Just added `[zZ]` as per the [RegExp docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html), there is also `\Z` anchor: *Matches end of string. If string ends with a newline, it matches just before newline*. I shortened the number of lines, my initial code was just a bit more illustrative.

Comment: Thank you! Rails emits the error `Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements` when you use anchors in route constraints. This solves that problem. :)

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- wouldn't it be easier to solve it the other way round, i.e. start with an anchor-less regex that can be used in your routes and *add* the anchors later on?

Comment: @Stefan The regex is defined in [a third-party gem](https://github.com/jlindsey/semantic/blob/master/lib/semantic/version.rb), so I don't have any control over it. Sure, I could simply not use the gem's regex and define my own anchor-less version, but I don't want to miss out on future updates to the gem's regex.

Comment: `remove_anchors(/(\A)/) # => /(\A)/`

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I agree there may be issues when an expressions is more complex. **XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I-**: Once you come across it, please drop a comment here. I will check something meanwhile, and update the answer eventually.

Answer (score 2):

> It is even possible to modify an existing regular expression like this in Ruby?

No, it is not possible to modify an existing `Regexp` *at all* in Ruby.

You can just look at [the available methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) and you will immediately see that there are no mutating methods.

There is exactly *one* method, which allows you to build a *new* `Regexp` from one or more existing `Regexp`s, namely [`Regexp::union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-c-union), but that won't help you here.

Pretty much the only thing you *can* do, is get a `String` representation of the `Regexp` using [`Regexp#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s), then parse that `String`, remove the anchors textually, and create a new `Regexp` from the `String` via [`Regexp::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-c-new). Note, however, that the syntax of Ruby `Regexp`s is anything but trivial to parse, this is not a simple endeavor.

It appears there is no documentation for the syntax of Ruby's `Regexp`s, so you will have to look at the parser: [`regparse.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/regparse.c)

Comment: No one is talking about modifying *existing* regexp object, but about *rebuilding* it.

Comment: The OP is talking about it, he even explicitly uses both the word "exisitng" and the word "modify": "It is even possible to modify an existing regular expression like this in Ruby?"

Answer (score 1):

According to [your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092048/how-to-programmatically-remove-anchors-from-a-regular-expression-in-ruby#comment52080056_32092467) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092048/how-to-programmatically-remove-anchors-from-a-regular-expression-in-ruby#comment52081097_32092467), you're actually trying to use the [regular expression](https://github.com/jlindsey/semantic/blob/master/lib/semantic/version.rb#L4) from the Semantic gem in your routes:

```
module Semantic
  class Version
    SemVerRegexp = /\A(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(\+([0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?\Z/
    # ...
  end
end
```

According to the [routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints): (you have already tried this)

> `:constraints` takes regular expressions with the restriction that regexp anchors can't be used.

But there's another way: can specify [advanced constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) as a lambda. Here's an example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/some/path/*version_str' => 'versions#show',
    format: false,
    constraints: lambda { |request| 
      Semantic::Version::SemVerRegexp =~ request.params[:version_str]
    }
end
```

`format: false` prevents Rails from extracting trailing dots.

Testing the route in `rails console`:

```
r = Rails.application.routes

r.recognize_path '/some/path/1.6.5'
#=> {:controller=>"versions", :action=>"show", :version_str=>"1.6.5"}

r.recognize_path '/some/path/3.7.9-pre.1+revision.15723'
#=> {:controller=>"versions", :action=>"show", :version_str=>"3.7.9-pre.1+revision.15723"}

r.recognize_path '/some/path/123'
#=> ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/some/path/123"
```

Comment: Pretty cool! But I need it to replace the `id` segment of a resource's routes. Do you know how to do that? For reference, this is currently my routing setup: `resources :packages, constraints: { id: remove_anchors(Semantic::Version::SemVerRegexp) }`

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- maybe you have to define the routes manually as shown above. After all, `resources` is just a helper to set up the default CRUD routes.